# “log4j:configuration” must match “(renderer….loggerFactory)?)”

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, log4j

getting error, when deploying my war file to tomcat:

```
log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match "(renderer*,throwableRenderer?,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)"
```

I googled around and found out that ordering of my log4j.xml could be wrong, but it should be correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">  

  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">  
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>  
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d %c %x - %m%n"/>  
    </layout>  
  </appender>  

  <root>  
    <priority value ="error" />  
    <appender-ref ref="console" />  
  </root>  

  <category name="org.springframework" additivity="false">  
    <priority value="info" />  
    <appender-ref ref="console" />  
  </category>  

</log4j:configuration>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

According to the error message, the DTD expects all `category` elements to be ahead of the `root` element.  You have them the wrong way round.

Answer (score 8):

Follow this order:

```
<renderer></renderer>

<appender></appender>

<plugin></plugin>

<logger></logger>

<category></category>

<root></root>

<loggerfactory></loggerfactory>

<categoryfactory></categoryfactory>
```