# Log4j warning log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)"

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I copied this properties file direct from [Apache website](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) and when I run it I receive a warning, hoping someone can help me

I am receiving this warning on my log4j properties file:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 20 and column 21
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 35 and column 21
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".
```

Here is the properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

elements have to be in correct order in the log4j file; that's why you are getting this error.The error is even specifying the order.
example:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: What if it's a xml file??

Comment: @mannedear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685217/how-to-solve-the-warnings-in-log4jcontinuable-parsing-error-the-content-of/25685351